# Get total number of members in Discord using PHP

Tags: php, discord

I have a Discord servern with 1361 members and on my website I want to display a total number of joined users.

I have figured out how to get all online Members on the server using:

```
   <?php

    $jsonIn = file_get_contents('https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/356230556738125824/widget.json');
    $JSON = json_decode($jsonIn, true);

    $membersCount = count($JSON['members']);

    echo "Number of members: " . $membersCount;
   ?>
```

What should I do differently to get a total number of ALL users that have joined the server, and not just display the online members?

Comment: You can use the api call /guilds/{guild.id}/members as described in the [API Documentation](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#list-guild-members)

Comment: @jrenk Does that require a library of some sort? I am completely new to PHP and just want to play around a bit, is there no way to do it similar to the code above?

Comment: you need to replace the line `$jsonIn = file_get_contents('https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/356230556738125824/widget.json');` with `$jsonIn = file_get_contents('https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/356230556738125824/members');`

Comment: @jrenk Hm I get 401: Unauthorized, Ill play around a bit and see what I can come up with thank you for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Now, I realize I am reviving a pretty old thread here, but I figure some might still use an answer. As jrenk pointed out, you should instead access `https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/356230556738125824/members`.

Your `404: Unauthorized` comes from the fact that you are -you guessed it- not authorized.
If you have created a bot, it is fairly easy: just add a request header `Authorization: Bot YOUR_BOT_TOKEN_HERE`. If you use a normal Discord account, the whole problem is a bit more tricky:
You will first have to send a `POST` request to `https://discordapp.com/api/auth/login` and set the body to `{"email": "EMAIL_HERE", "password": "PASSWORD_HERE"}`.
You will get a response with the parameter `token`. Save this token, you will need it later. BUT:

> **NEVER, UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCES** show anyone this token, as it is equivalent to your login credentials!

With this token, you can now send a `POST` request to the same address: `https://discordapp.com/api/auth/login`, but now add the header `Authorization: YOUR_BOT_TOKEN_HERE`. Note the missing "Bot" at the beginning.

Also, what you mustn't forget:

> If you don't add the parameter `?limit=MAX_USERS`, you will only get the first guild member. Take a look [here](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#list-guild-members) to see details.

Answer (score 2):

You have to count the number of online member 
here is the working code

```
<?php
$members = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/356230556738125824/widget.json'), true)['members'];
$membersCount = 1;
foreach ($members as $member) {
    if ($member['status'] == 'online') {
        $membersCount++;
    }
}
echo "Number of members: " . $membersCount;
?>
```

Comment: I do not want to get online players I want to display the total number of users that have joined the server, I currently have 1362 members on the server.

Comment: then simple remove the if condition


foreach ($members as $member) {
        $membersCount++;
}

Comment: you have 1362 members but i can see only 300

Comment: Hm odd according to Discord in server settings I have 1362 https://gyazo.com/69117f42c2d7bd5d486ed3e7b32adf3d

Comment: i can see in channel total 30 and in members array tota 305 members are ther

Answer (score 1):

You need a bot on your discord server to get all members. Use the Discord js library for example.

Answer (score 0):

First create a discord bot and get a token, see the following url:
https://github.com/reactiflux/discord-irc/wiki/Creating-a-discord-bot-&-getting-a-token

As @2Kreeper noted, do not reveal your token publicly.

Then use the following code, replacing "***enter-bot-token-here***" and "***enter-guild-id-here***" with your own information:

```
<?php

$json_options = [
  "http" => [
    "method" => "GET",
    "header" => "Authorization: Bot enter-bot-token-here"
  ]
];

$json_context = stream_context_create($json_options);

$json_get     = file_get_contents('https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/enter-guild-id-here/members?limit=1000', false, $json_context);

$json_decode  = json_decode($json_get, true);

echo '<h2>Member Count</h2>';
echo count($json_decode);

echo '<h2>JSON Output</h2>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($json_decode);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still interested, here's the solution I currently use using [RestCord](https://www.restcord.com/):

```
use RestCord\DiscordClient;

$serverId = <YourGuildId>;

$discord = new DiscordClient([
    'token' => '<YourBotToken>'
]);

$limit = 1000;
$membercnt = 0;
$_ids = array();

function getTotalUsersCount($ids, $limit, $serverId, $discord) {
    if( count($ids) > 0 ) {
        $last_id = max($ids);
        $last_id = (int)$last_id;
    } else {
        $last_id = null;
    }
    $members = $discord->guild->listGuildMembers(['guild.id' => $serverId, 'limit' => $limit, 'after' => $last_id]);
    $_ids = array();
    foreach( $members as $member ) {
        $ids[] = $member->user->id;
        $_ids[] = $member->user->id;
    }

    if( count($_ids) > 0 ) {
        return getTotalUsersCount($ids, $limit, $serverId, $discord);
    } else {
        return $ids;
    }
}

$ids = getTotalUsersCount($_ids, $limit, $serverId, $discord);
$membercnt = count($ids);

echo "Member Count: " . $membercnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Soubhagya Kumar's answer comment by iTeY you can simply use count(), there is no need to loop if you do not require a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reviving this since it still seems to be relevant and the other answers seem a bit too complex I think (maybe the API used to be bad(?)). So:

Generate a **permanent** discord invite and keep the code at the end (https://discord.gg/xxxxxxx) and then all you do is this:

```
<?php
    $server_code = "xxxxxxx";
    $url = "https://discord.com/api/v9/invites/".$server_code."?with_counts=true&with_expiration=true";
        
    $jsonIn = file_get_contents($url);
    $json_obj = json_decode($jsonIn, $assoc = false);
    $total = $json_obj ->approximate_member_count;
?>
```

And there you go, that's the total member count. Keep in mind, this will also count the bots I think so you have to account for that if you want to refine it even more