# Get total number of members in Discord using PHP?

Tags: php, discord

```
<?php
$json_options = [
  "http" => [
    "method" => "GET",
    "header" => "Authorization: Bot xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  ]
];

$json_context = stream_context_create($json_options);
$json_get     = file_get_contents('https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/111111111111111/members?limit=1000', false, $json_context);
$json_decode  = json_decode($json_get, true);

echo '<h2>Member Count</h2>';
echo count($json_decode);

echo '<h2>JSON Output</h2>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($json_decode);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Here is my code .  I created discord bot , when i paste url i get 401 . I can get online number ,but i need total members ,but no luck .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get total number of members in Discord using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47454876/get-total-number-of-members-in-discord-using-php)

Comment: also, make sure you have access to ``GUILD_MEMBERS`` for the application.

Comment: no ,before this post i already checked

Comment: do i need any  libaries for guild_members?

Comment: If you get a 401 error it means you aren't authenticated properly. Perhaps your auth code is wrong or expired. Check the API documentation for how to authenticate correctly.

Comment: Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74583912/3754344